Is the range of change of the mass of water in this device due to a change in volume? (see below)
I've been reading Potter's book about fluid mechanics and I've got a doubt about an example.
Here is the problem.

My doubt relates to the fact that the resolution states that
$$\frac{dm}{dt}=\frac{d}{dt}\int_{c.v}\rho \ dV$$
where ${c.v}$ refers to the control volume that it's kind of shown in the picture. I don´t get what´s changing with time in that integral. I believe the density doesn´t change because we generally assume it constant as it's water. I tend to think that what changes with time it´s the control volume since at the end of the resolution the book says

Hence the mass is increasing at the rate of 1.975 slug/sec. To accomplish this, the device
could have a spongelike material that absorbs water.

considering that true I logically think that the control volume change because inside the device there's a "sponge" that absorbes water at the rate of 1.975 slugs/sec what means there's more volume inside that increases with time since looking from out the device we see less water goes out that the water we let in.
So in order to summarize my doubt, I don´t get if I´m correct that in the integral shown above what changes with time is the differential volume (the volume after all) and not the density.

You need to remember mass balance, namely $\frac{d}{dt} \int_V \rho = -\oint_{\partial V} \rho \mathbf{u} \cdot \mathbf{\hat{n}} $. You have everything you need, if density is assumed to be constant and given.

That I understand but what intrigues me is what part of the integral (the one on the left side on your equation) is that varies with time. Is it the volume what is dependent on time?

Perhaps the device is a bathtub that is filling up with water?

@user403871 oh, I misunderstood then. Yeah, it could be a reservoir containing some air. Just perform the mass balance on the "water phase"

As an aside, who still does physics in feet, inches, and slug units? I studied fluid mechanics in 1988-1989 and everything was in metric back then. I've never seen a physics or engineering book from the late 1970s or later that didn't use exclusively metric units. My dad used those units in when he was getting his engineering degree the early 1950s, but that was a long time ago.

Those units still appear on many books just to make one aware of it since they´re still used in some places around the world. Of course the metric system is the widely used and mainly teach (at least in Argentina) but american books prefer to treat the calculus with both systems.

In the control volume approach, the control volume is a black box, and it does not matter what the details of what is happening in the box are.
